# Angular parent and multiple child content projection

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I am trying to create common component like below.

```
<card-list-layout [type]=“type”>
  <card>
    Card 1
  </card>
  
  <card>
    Card 2
  </card>
</card-list-layout>
```

Here type can be “card” or “list”, depending on type layout will get change.
I am not getting how can I project Card childs in my common component